# Regex for matching code blocks that don't have blank lines afterwards

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, replace

I want to clean up my code and add blank lines after code blocks.

For example:

```
if (foo)
{
    DoFooStuff();
}
if (bar)
{
    DoBarStuff();
}
else
{    
    try
    {
        MightThrowError();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex);
    }
}
MoreStuffToDo(true);
```

I find this code much easier to read if there is a blank line before `if (bar)`, so you can see that there are two distinct conditionals here. I would therefore like to match all cases similar to **line 4** and **the second last line** and add a new line. However, it should not match the curly brace before "else", "catch" and the one on the third last line which is another curly brace in a nested block.

I am using the Find function in Visual Studio 2017 and my code is C#. My desired result on the above example is:

```
if (foo)
{
    DoFooStuff();
}

if (bar)
{
    DoBarStuff();
}
else
{    
    try
    {
        MightThrowError();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex);
    }
}

MoreStuffToDo(true);
```

I have tried the following regular expression:

```
}[\r\n]\t*.
```

(i.e. match a close curly brace, a newline, then any number of tabs, then any non-newline character.)

I need it to also match spaces as well as tabs (how do I make it "or"?) and ideally I need to not match following closing curly braces, as well as the words `else`, `catch` and `finally`. I am prepared to do some of the work manually, though.

**Is what I'm looking for possible and if so, what would be the regular expression?**

Comment: Do you mean you want to match a line with a single `}`  on it that is followed with a line starting with `if` and then insert a newline? Try `^([\t\p{Zs}]*}[\t\p{Zs}]*)\r\n([\t\p{Zs}]*if)\b` and replace with `$1\r\n\r\n$2`

Comment: You have to **parse** the code to find the blocks. RegEx is **not for parsing**

Comment: Not necessarily the word "if". Any statement that follows a code block without a blank line (and isn't related to the block, like 'else' would be). No regex is not for parsing, but if it is possible to use regex for my purpose this would be a lot easier.

Comment: So, how can you define the context? If you cannot do that, no regex will work here.

Comment: What do you mean by the context? I wish to run this against a visual studio solution with several hundred code files.

Comment: A downvote and a close flag as "too broad"? I'm asking for a very specific regex, for a specific language and engine, with an examples of matches and non-matches, with a pattern that isn't working, and a description of the desired results. Can anyone suggest ways to improve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the symbol:
    |
for logical or in Regex. For example:

```
}[\r\n][\t*|\s*].
```

Should match any number of tabs or any number of whitespace. But since tab is a whitespace character you could just use

```
}[\r\n][\s*].
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on logical OR. 

I can't use `\s` because that matches any whitespace characters, including newlines.

Comment: In that case you can just use an actual space instead of \s

Comment: Try it on [this](https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/3da418af4c632449edb7b85984b0522f)

Comment: Pipe in a character class doen't means `or` but simply a pipe character.